# Automorphism of the coordinate ring of a linear algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let me define a linear algebraic group first of all:

A linear algebraic group is an affine variety (zeroes of a set of polynomials in $n$ variables with coefficients in a field $C$) such that the maps 
 $$\phi : G \times G  \to G $$
 $$(x,y) \mapsto xy$$

and
   $$\psi : G \to G$$ 
   $$x \mapsto x^{-1}$$

are morphisms of varieties.

As I understand (please correct if I am wrong), $G$ contains points in $C^n$ as well as $K^n$ where $K$ is a field extension of $C$.

Now, G acts on iteslf by right multiplication : 
  Let $g \in G$ be a $C$-point ,i.e, $g \in C^n$ and consider the map

$$\rho_{g} : G \to G $$
$$h \mapsto hg$$

This map is ofcourse a bijection. I do not see that it as a homomorphism though. (please correct if I am wrong).

Now, I have read in a few books that this map $\rho_{g}$ induces an $C$-algebra automorphism :

$$\rho^{*}_g : C[G] \to C[G]$$
$$ f \mapsto f.\rho_g$$

Note that $C[G]$ is the coordinate ring of $G$, i.e, $C[G]= C[x_1,...,x_n]/I(G) $ where $I(G)$ is the ideal consisting of all polynomials satisfied by $G$.

Now, I have few doubts which I state below:

1. Since $g$ is a $C$-point, I can realise that $f.\rho_g$ indeed is in $C[G]$ but what if $g$ is not a $C$-point. What happens then ?
2. I have checked that $\rho^{*}_g$ is an additive homorphism and a bijection. But I am failing to realise it as a ring homomorphism. Please help me regarding this.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

1. If $g$ is a $K$-point then it gives an automorphism of $K[G]$.
2. This is equivalent to the claim that the corresponding map $G \to G$ is a map of varieties, which is true because the multiplication map is a map of varieties.

Comment: I understand the answer to the first doubt. But for the second part can you give me a reference where it is explicitly shown that the morphism of the varieties $\rho_{g}$ in this case, induce a $C$-algebra automorphism between the coordinate rings. Thank you for answering ! I mean I help me in realising $\rho^*_{g}(f_1f_2)= \rho^*_{g}(f_1)\rho^*_{g}(f_2)$.

Comment: Please help  me in realising that !